# Return value of key from dictionary nested in a list Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, variables

I have the following variable in my python script:

```
response = {"tasks": [{"attachments": [{"id": "id123xyz", "type": "ElasticNetworkInterface", "status": "PRECREATED", "details": [{"name": "john doe"}] }]}]}
```

I am simply trying to return the value of status. However, I'm unable to do so.

Comment: You mean: `print(response['tasks'][0]['attachments'][0]['status'])`? Result: `PRECREATED`

Answer (score 1):

You need to index into each dictionary and list that the status is inside.

You can do the following:

```py
# Prints "PRECREATED"
print(response["tasks"][0]["attachments"][0]["status"])
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to access the dictionary and the list that is inside:

```
status = response['tasks'][0]['attachments'][0]['status']

#output
'PRECREATED'
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the `status`, you can do this

`response['tasks'][0]['attachments'][0]['status']`

If you would like to extract to dictionary or array of id and status then we can do:

```
dict([(attachment['id'], attachment['status']) for task in response['tasks'] for attachment in task['attachments']])

returns:
{'id123xyz': 'PRECREATED'}
```

Comment: This was Flawless. Thank you